# Selenium - Switch to dynamic iframe after onclick button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch into a new frame, which opens after clicking a button. Unfortunately, I receive a *None* value.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.milanuncios.com/dacia-de-segunda-mano/dacia-sandero-1-5-dci-exportacion-323650137.htm')
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="pagAnuShowContactForm"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Till here, it works to open the contact information. Here, I would like to perform actions in the new, opened window.
I tried the following options:

1.

```
contact = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

2.

```
contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="telefonos"]')
```

Comment: https://www.milanuncios.com/distil_identify_cookie.html?httpReferrer=%2Fdacia-de-segunda-mano%2Fdacia-sandero-1-5-dci-exportacion-323650137.htm your link is not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the telephone number.The element is present inside iframe ID `ifrw` you need to switch to iframe first.

Induce `WebDriverWait` And `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce  `WebDriverWait` And `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.milanuncios.com/dacia-de-segunda-mano/dacia-sandero-1-5-dci-exportacion-323650137.htm')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='pagAnuShowContactForm']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"ifrw")))
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".telefonos"))).text.strip())
driver.close()
```

**Output**:

```
663473583
```